# Twilio video calling between clients

Tags: twilio

last two week I am playing around with Twilio Video SDK
In my demo application I have integrated both voice and video SDK, I do have following question please help me out

**1)how make/receive video call just by using client name (client to client call)( same as Voice client to client call )?

2)how to switch between voice and video call ?

3)how to invite participant in an ongoing video call ?**

Thanks